# Is there non-GPU equivalent of tf_utils package?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using CPU based tensorflow (on non GPU platform) from python. I want to use functionality like load_dataset, random_mini_batches, convert_to_one_hot etc. from tf_utils package. However the one from neuroailab github has dependency on tensorflow-gpu. Is there any other CPU based (for non GPU platform) equivalent package for this?

Comment: Having a dependency on tensorflow-gpu does not mean the code does not run on CPU. I would try first.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro: When I install tf_utils from neuroailab repository in my working tensorflow CPU container, I get an error stating: "ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory." while importing tensorflow. I believe it must be because of GPU dependency of tf_utils from whatever I could find about such error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas already has quite a bit of functionality that tf_utils provides. E.g.

1. read_csv could capture what I was looking for from load_dataset.
2. get_dummies does what convert_to_one_hot does.
3. I could not find any direct functionality in pandas that came close to random_mini_batches but it can be achieved with sampling and random numbers.